# How do I load a webcomponent across domains?

Tags: nginx, firefox, web-component

Can you not load webcomponents from other domains?

I'm getting a cors error in firefox/linux.

I added this to nginx but still can't load it:

```
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <script type="module" src="//briskreader.com/components/feed-list.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <feed-list topic="bitcoin"></feed-list>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://briskreader.com/components/feed-list.js. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Loading module from “http://briskreader.com/components/feed-list.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
test.html
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://briskreader.com/components/feed-list.js. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

Heres the header from briskreader.com:

```
$ curl -I 'https://briskreader.com/components/feed-list.js'
HTTP/2 200 
server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
date: Sun, 21 Nov 2021 06:30:51 GMT
content-type: application/javascript
content-length: 2187
expires: Sun, 21 Nov 2021 06:30:50 GMT
cache-control: no-cache
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0
access-control-allow-origin: *
accept-ranges: bytes
```

Comment: CORS is about accessing files, it has nothing to do with web components

Answer (score 0):

Web components has nothing to do with CORS. The attribute `type="module"` on `<script>` tag causes the CORS request. Unlike classic scripts, **module scripts** require the use of the CORS protocol for cross-origin fetching.

Next this line `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;` is useless on origin domain. You must set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on `briskreader.com` domain. If you do not control `briskreader.com`, then consider using classical script. You can still use Web components with classical script.

Comment: I did set it on briskrsader and it’s still not working.

Comment: @chovy Can you share the response header for the request to `//briskreader.com/components/feed-list.js`?

Comment: updated question, as you can see it has `access-control-allow-origin: *`

Comment: so here's the problem. i was using `http-server` which uses http and my server redirected http -> https which won't work for protocol agnostic urls I guess. Weird.

Comment: If i change the `src` attribute of the module from `//` to `https://` it works fine.

Comment: Ideally `//` should work. But that's strange. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: I upvoted (from a -1 vote status). [in my layman words] ``//`` means: do the request with the protocol the requester is running, so a page served with HTTP makes an HTTP request; then the HTTP**S** server will block it, since it is an insecure request. Do a 2 minute Google search and you'll get plenty of answers.

Comment: I thought that `briskreader.com` is also serving on `http` and not just `https`.